# jquery selectors and sibblings

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
<div>
 <div class="pr-selec">some text</div>
 ...
</div>


<div>
 <div class="pr-selec">some text</div>
 <div class="new-class">other text</div>
 ...
</div>
```

using jQuery, how can I select only the `.pr-selec` div classes that do NOT have a sibbiling `.new-class` div?

I was trying something like this:

```
jQuery(".pr-selec").not().sibblings("new-class").each({
            //stuff
        });
```

but that wasn't doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Try [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with [:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [next-sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

```
$('.pr-selec').not(':has(~ .new-class)').css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CLet7/)

Note: This will not work if the `new-class` element is not the next sibling(previous): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CLet7/2/)

Comment: really like this solution.  thank you.  in my case, the `new-class` is always the next sibbling

Comment: That is pretty clever! +1, but as you said, it work only on next element and is slower than `filter` : http://jsperf.com/test-siblings

Answer (score 3):

You are better using `filter`:

```
jQuery(".pr-selec").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).siblings('.new-class').length;
}).each(...)
```